# Windows to Mac: Should my home folder act now as my entire D drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, windows, migration

I am migrating from Windows to a new Mac, and I just noticed that after Mac OS Catalina, I can not create any folders under root directory (/).
Should all my data go to my user's home folder, as if it was a root drive in Windows like "D:"?

Comment: Assuming that your D:\ drive was a secondary drive that you created to store your files on then yes. Put everything in your user home folder.

Comment: And have an Admin account with admin privileges and a user account with only user privileges. May avoid you deleting the wrong stuff.